# How to demote an Endorser from Hyperledger Indy?

Tags: python, hyperledger-indy

I am currently using the example of Hyperledger Indy of [Write a DID and Query Its Verkey](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/main/docs/how-tos/write-did-and-query-verkey/README.md) to dive deep into DID creation.

After generating a DID and a verkey for a TRUST_ANCHOR, I sign and submit it to the ledger as:

```
            # 7.
            print_log('\n7. Building NYM request to add Trust Anchor to the ledger\n')
            nym_transaction_request = await ledger.build_nym_request(submitter_did=user.steward_did,
                                                                    target_did=actor_did,
                                                                    ver_key=actor_verkey,
                                                                    alias=None,
                                                                    role='TRUST_ANCHOR')

            print_log('NYM transaction request: ')
            pprint.pprint(json.loads(nym_transaction_request))

            # 8.
            print_log('\n8. Sending NYM request to the ledger\n')
            nym_transaction_response = await ledger.sign_and_submit_request(pool_handle=pool_handle,
                                                                            wallet_handle=wallet_handle,
                                                                            submitter_did=user.steward_did,
                                                                            request_json=nym_transaction_request)
```

I wanted to demote this TRUST_ANCHOR from the ledger, removing its rights and making it disappear, is it possible?

Reading the [AUTH_RULES](https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/main/docs/source/auth_rules.md) it seems possible as there are many lines in this table about demoting roles. But I don't see how to implement it on Python.

Answer (score 0):

On indy-cli you remove the role with this txn:

```
ledger nym did=THE_DID_TO_REMOVE_ROLE_FROM role=
```

This is probably what you want on python, run this to remove the did's role:

```
nym_transaction_request = await ledger.build_nym_request(submitter_did=user.steward_did,
                                                                    target_did=actor_did,
                                                                    ver_key=actor_verkey,
                                                                    alias=None,
                                                                    role='')
```

and of course you have to sign and submit the request after creating it.

```
 await ledger.sign_and_submit_request(pool_handle=pool_handle,
                                                                        wallet_handle=wallet_handle,
                                                                        submitter_did=user.steward_did,
                                                                        request_json=nym_transaction_request)
```

if you look at the ledger after the request, you will see that the last transaction is a DID transaction with no role.